# Is this kind of LCD streaking on my monitor already irrepairable?

Tags: display, lcd

With the streaks of my monitor, it's been hard to read with it. It rendered useless for my research. However, I'm thinking if I should still get it checked and repaired or if it would be better to just buy a new one.

[image: Image of monitor with rectangular areas of a different brightness]

Comment: The first thing to do is try a different monitor - assuming you have another or can borrow one for a few minutes. It is possible that it is the video card in the computer which has a problem.

Comment: Or try the monitor on a different computer. (Too late to edit my earlier comment.)

Comment: Interesting error pattern. Please provide all details about your setup: Exact make and model of all devices involved, type of connection (VGA, HDMI, DVI, …) and anything else you think could be of relevance.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry to only see this now. I've tried a different monitor and my GPU is still fine. I tried using a different chord on my broken monitor and still the same image shows; however using the chord I originally use on my broken monitor on a fixed monitor, display is still okay hence, the monitor itself is really the problem. This is an IPS monitor using a DP port, specifically the SpecterPro 24GX-IPS 144hz Freesync Gaming Monitor. I've used it for 2 years until this happened. I appreciate your help in this.

Comment: @Christine Have you tried tapping the monitor to see if the pattern changes? If it does then it could be a loose connector inside. Do you have any electronics repair shops near you? I don't think the price of the monitor warrants posting it for repair.